# What does JUnit do in an Android project?

Tags: android, gradle, junit

I was interested to see what will happen if I delete this line `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` in `build.gradle` . so I comment that in a simple project and nothing happened and the app was run and behave just as before. 
So the question is what does `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` do in project? It has any Specified duty to do? What will happen if I omit that in every projects?

Comment: JUnit is a testing framework... obviously if you don't write test, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a framework for unit tests.  It isn't used in the actual app, its only compiled in when you build the unit test suite (that's why its testCompile instead of compile).

If you remove it, you won't have a way of writing unit tests (or you'd need to build your own framework).  It won't effect your app itself.

Comment: so the app can be run without any problem?

Comment: Yes.  Just not tested.